# jQuery toggle one div with same class

Tags: jquery, class, html, toggle

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NhPg6/) for my hover event.

Currently on hover all divs of the same class are toggled. I'm wanting to toggle just the one div (that which is being hovered on). I've tried a few filters but can't seem to work it out.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to search for a `.foo2` in the same `.container` of the link:

```
$(".container a").hover(function()
{
    $('.foo2', $(this).parent()).toggle();
});​
```